# Possible to specify two DIFFERENT layouts for portrait and landscape?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

The C# samples and source code I've seen for Win8 Metro-style apps use storyboard animations to modify a page for different views (not just different full-screen orientations, but *snapped* and *filled* view modes as well).

This seems like a good way to adjust your view for different resolutions, orientations, etc, but...

I sometimes get UI specs for portrait & landscape views that require a very different internal structure of `<Grid>` and `<StackPanel>` tags. Trying to morph one of these structures into the other using an animation seems like a pretty daunting task, not to mention difficult to maintain as the spec matures.

Before I resign myself to taking the animate-a-single-layout approach, I wanted to make sure that it ***isn't*** possible to simply specify two completely separate XAML layouts, similar to how it works in Android?

Anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: You can definitely switch between layouts using visual state manager. In XAML animations are not just about animating things. You can change style or show/hide different elements using animations.

Comment: +1 on Denis. You could use the VSM to enable/disable a whole block of controls. It makes a big XAML though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only downside is that you have a big duplicated XAML, much like you already do for Landscape/Filled vs. Snapped.

However, what you can do is animate some specific properties on your Landscape layout if that gets you where you need to be.

For instance, if have a `GridView` and your boxes need to go from 250x250 to 200x300, you can just copy the style you use for your `ItemTemplate`, tweak it so that the width and height values are correct, and use a `Storyboard` change your `ItemTemplate` from `"Standard250x250"` to `"MyNewPortrait200x300Style"`.

Now, if it is a fundamental change, like the difference between a `GridView` and a `ListView`, you might just have to live with some duplicated layout code and using some `Storyboard`s to collapse one and show the other (like the templates do with Landscape/Filled vs. Snapped).

**Edit**

To be clear, I am saying your best options are to either tweak the styling properties via animations, or create an entirely separate `Panel` (be it a `Grid`, `StackPanel`, or whatever) for your other layout and use an animation to set the `Visibility` on the Landscape one to `Collapsed` and the Portrait one to `Visible`. That's how the Grid Template handles Snapped, and it works really nicely. Much easier than trying to morph each and every child control of your root panel.